# dateutils default to the last occurence of recognized part, not next

Tags: python, datetime, date-parsing, python-dateutil

I am using [`dateutils.parser.parse`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) to parse date strings which might contain partial information. If some information is not present, `parse` can take a `default` keyword argument from which it will fill any missing fields. This default defaults to `datetime.datetime.today()`.

For a case like `dateutil.parser.parse("Thursday")`, this means it will return the date of the *next* Thursday. However, I need it to return the date of the *last* Thursday (including today, if today happens to be a Thursday).

So, assuming `today == datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 20)` (a Tuesday), I would like to get all of these `assert`s to be true:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

def parse(date_str, default=None):
    # this needs to be modified
    return parser.parse(date_str, default=default)

today = datetime(2018, 2, 20)

assert parse("Tuesday", default=today) == today    # True
assert parse("Thursday", default=today) == datetime(2018, 2, 15)    # False
assert parse("Jan 31", default=today) == datetime(2018, 1, 31)    # True
assert parse("December 10", default=today) == datetime(2017, 12, 10)    # False
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? With the current `parse` function only the first and third `assert` would pass.

Comment: It doesn't default to last or next, it just replaces the components of the default with the ones it finds in the string

Comment: @Paul You are correct, will re-word.

Comment: Compare if that weekday(date) have passed or not, if not passed, minus a weekday(a year).

Comment: @Paul Hm, `dateutil.parser.parse("Thursday", default=datetime.datetime.(2018, 12, 31) == datetime.datetime.(2019, 1, 3)`, though.

Comment: @Graipher Thursday with 2018/2/20 was parsed to 2018/2/22, 2018/12/31 was parsed to 2019/1/3. Both of the results are the following day Thursday of the given day, is there anything looks strange?

Comment: So you want to get last occurrence of all the date ?

Comment: @DavidPage Well, that is just the behavior of `datutil.parser.parse`, but this is not the one I need. I would need them to parse to 2018/02/15 and 2018/12/27.

Comment: @VikasDamodar I want `"Thursday"` to parse to the date of the last Thursday (with respect to some reference), `"Dec 10"` to be the last day with that date (regardless if it was this or last year) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your modified code (*code.py*):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


today = datetime(2018, 2, 20)

data = [
    ("Tuesday", today, today),
    ("Thursday", datetime(2018, 2, 15), today),
    ("Jan 31", datetime(2018, 1, 31), today),
    ("December 10", datetime(2017, 12, 10), today),
]


def parse(date_str, default=None):
    # this needs to be modified
    return parser.parse(date_str, default=default)


def _days_in_year(year):
    try:
        datetime(year, 2, 29)
    except ValueError:
        return 365
    return 366


def parse2(date_str, default=None):
    dt = parser.parse(date_str, default=default)
    if default is not None:
        weekday_strs = [day_str.lower() for day_tuple in parser.parserinfo.WEEKDAYS for day_str in day_tuple]
        if date_str.lower() in weekday_strs:
            if dt.weekday() > default.weekday():
                dt -= timedelta(days=7)
        else:
            if (dt.month > today.month) or ((dt.month == today.month) and (dt.day > today.day)):
                dt -= timedelta(days=_days_in_year(dt.year))
    return dt


def print_stats(parse_func):
    print("\nPrinting stats for \"{:s}\"".format(parse_func.__name__))
    for triple in data:
        d = parse_func(triple[0], default=triple[2])
        print("  [{:s}] [{:s}] [{:s}] [{:s}]".format(triple[0], str(d), str(triple[1]), "True" if d == triple[1] else "False"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    print_stats(parse)
    print_stats(parse2)
```

**Notes**:

- I changed the structure of the code "a bit", to parametrize it, so if a change is needed (e.g. a new example to be added) the changes should be minimal

  - Instead of *assert*s, I added a function (*print_stats*) that prints the results (instead raising *AssertError* and exiting the program if things don't match)

    - Takes an argument (*parse_func*) which is a function that does the parsing (e.g. *parse*)
    - Uses some globally declared data (*data*) together with the (above) function
  - *data* - is a list of triples, where each triple contains:

    1. Text to be converted
    2. Expected *datetime* ([[Python 3.Docs]: datetime Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)) to be yielded by the conversion
    3. *default* argument to be passed to the parsing function (*parse_func*)
- *parse2* function (an improved version of *parse*):

  - Accepts 2 types of date strings:

    1. Weekday name
    2. Month / Day (unordered)
  - Does the regular parsing, and if the converted object comes **after** the one passed as the *default* argument (that is determined by comparing the appropriate attributes of the 2 objects), it subtracts a period (take a look at [[Python 3.Docs]: timedelta Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)):

    1. "Thursday" comes after "Tuesday", so it subtracts the number of days in a week (7)
    2. "December 10" comes after "February 20", so it subtracts the number of days in the year<sup>*****</sup>
  - *weekday_strs*: I'd better explain it by example:

    > ```py
    > >>> parser.parserinfo.WEEKDAYS
    > [('Mon', 'Monday'), ('Tue', 'Tuesday'), ('Wed', 'Wednesday'), ('Thu', 'Thursday'), ('Fri', 'Friday'), ('Sat', 'Saturday'), ('Sun', 'Sunday')]
    > >>> [day_str.lower() for day_tuple in parser.parserinfo.WEEKDAYS for day_str in day_tuple]
    > ['mon', 'monday', 'tue', 'tuesday', 'wed', 'wednesday', 'thu', 'thursday', 'fri', 'friday', 'sat', 'saturday', 'sun', 'sunday']
    > ```

    - Flattens `parser.parserinfo.WEEKDAYS`
    - Converts strings to lowercase (for simplifying comparisons)
- *_days_in_year*<sup>*****</sup> - as you probably guessed, returns the number of days in an year (couldn't simply subtract 365 because *leap* years might mess things up):

  > ```py
  > >>> dt = datetime(2018, 3, 1)
  > >>> dt
  > datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0)
  > >>> dt - timedelta(365)
  > datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0)
  > >>> dt = datetime(2016, 3, 1)
  > >>> dt
  > datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0)
  > >>> dt - timedelta(365)
  > datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 2, 0, 0)
  > ```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048884480>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> Printing stats for "parse"
>   [Tuesday] [2018-02-20 00:00:00] [2018-02-20 00:00:00] [True]
>   [Thursday] [2018-02-22 00:00:00] [2018-02-15 00:00:00] [False]
>   [Jan 31] [2018-01-31 00:00:00] [2018-01-31 00:00:00] [True]
>   [December 10] [2018-12-10 00:00:00] [2017-12-10 00:00:00] [False]
>
> Printing stats for "parse2"
>   [Tuesday] [2018-02-20 00:00:00] [2018-02-20 00:00:00] [True]
>   [Thursday] [2018-02-15 00:00:00] [2018-02-15 00:00:00] [True]
>   [Jan 31] [2018-01-31 00:00:00] [2018-01-31 00:00:00] [True]
>   [December 10] [2017-12-10 00:00:00] [2017-12-10 00:00:00] [True]
> ```